# Sonarqube plugin for Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp

Tags: c#, sonarqube, code-analysis, roslyn-code-analysis, microsoft.codeanalysis

I'm trying to report code analysis from Visual Studio into the SonarQube server.

I'm unable to port the rules from Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp and could not generate a plugin with the Sonar Roslyn Sdk project due to errors. Is there a plugin available for this anlyzer or how am I supposed to make it work with SonarQube?

Thanks for help

Comment: Which errors did you get?

Comment: [Here is the complete output](http://i.imgur.com/yR9AaQK.png)

Comment: Is there any rules contained in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp?